# Core Data derived attribute not calculated properly on first use?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, derived-attribute

I have Company entity in Core Data that has relationship one-to-many Activities

I've added there derived property to Company

```
activities.@count
```

but then accessing in SwiftUI view this property gives me invalid result. It usually works ok but on logout/login where I think there is company update and relationship update it for the first time gives 0 count of activities in spite there are activities related to company

using this

```
self.user?.company?.activitiesCount ?? 0
```

gives 0

using this

```
self.user?.company?.activities.count ?? 0
```

gives 75

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple documentation on Derived Attributes for Core Data

> Data recomputes derived attributes when you save a context. A managed object’s property does not reflect unsaved changes until you save the context and refresh the object.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsderivedattributedescription?language=swift